# Is it possible to use a bare infinitive for the object of an "of"?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, bare-infinitives

For example, "I described the scene of *him* **drive** away."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I described the scene of him drive away.

should be:

- I described the scene of **him/his driving** away."

That said, I would write that sentence like this:

- I described the scene in which he drives away.

**driving away** is a **gerund phrase**, in the prepositional phrase introduced by of.

a gerund phrase is basically a type of noun phrase.

Other examples:
playing tennis
going out
finishing work

Here are examples of one after the preposition of and about:

- The story **of his playing tennis** on that roof court was so funny.
- The lie **about his going out** was terrible.

So, no, a bare infinitive does not work, a gerund is needed.